# Incrementar um conteúdo achado pelo regex e incrementar com outras strings

Tags: regex

preciso de mais uma ajuda com o regex, como faço p encontrar em um texto um determinado padrão e incluir algo junto da string que encontrou.
EX:

```
"programacao": "11h Abertura – Som Mecânico 12h30 Lino e Orquestra 15h30 Volkstanzgruppe Blauer Berg - Timbó - SC (Infanto Juvenil) 15h45.
```

Toda vez que encontrar o padrao `xxhxx(12h30)` por exemplo, substitui com o mesmo conteúdo e inclui `<br>` ficando assim `<br>12h30.`

Comment: você quer capturar somente o 12h30? ou quer capturar todas as horas e colocar a tag <br>?

Comment: Quero capturar todas as horas e colocar <br>antes, estou usando o sublime text, ele nao reconhece o $1

Comment: editei a resposta com o formato que pode ser inserido no sublime

Comment: aliás, +1 bela pergunta

Comment: Obrigado, +1 pela ajuda ai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resposta**
Use essa regex p/ capturar:

```
(\d{2}h\d{0,2})
```

Na parte de substituição use:

```
<br>\1
```

[Você pode ver o funcionamento dessa regex aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/MxWuDc/2/)

**Explicação**

- `\d` - identifica um número (0-9), equivalente a `[0-9]`
- `{2}` - impõe que é necessário achar 2 dígitos seguidos para dar o *match*.
- `h` - da match com o caractere h
- `\d` - identifica um número (0-9), equivalente a `[0-9]`
- `{0,2}` - impõe que o padrão anterior deve ser encontrado entre 0 e 2 vezes, afinal a hora pode ser representada como `12h` = `12h00`.
- `<br>\1` - na parte de substituição você pode usar esse padrão para inserir `<br>`e o que foi capturado no grupo 1 através do sinal `\`